# Android image from sqlite won't show

Tags: android, sqlite, arrays, blob

I have an android app, where I need to take a picture and store it as a byte array (blob in SQLite), for future purpouses and retrieving this image back and show it. But it won't show. I checked the method for creating table, there is `BLOB` type, also I checked that I am retrieving data with `cursor.getBlob()`.
For capturing I followed up this tutorial http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html exept my `onActivityResult` looks different, because I wass getting null data (naturally, because I stored that picture already):

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    InputStream iStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);
                    inputData = getBytes(iStream);
        }
    }
```

and `inputData` is what am I storing in my `SQLite` database as a `BLOB`. Note that method `getBytes` is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10297073/2966401
This is how I am returning picture from db:

```
public byte[] getAttachment(int taskId) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_TASKS, new String[] {  KEY_ATTACHMENT1 }, 
        KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(taskId) },
        null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();
return cursor.getBlob(0);
}
```

And here I am calling it and filling into ImageView:

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.attachment);    
byte b[] = db.getAttachment(task.id);
Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
imgView.setImageBitmap(bp);
```

Note that `bp` is not null. 
This is the layout where attachment is, that background image is just to see if it shows right:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".TaskDetailActivity" >   
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >   

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/attachment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
            android:src="@drawable/background" />
 </RelativeLayout>    
</ScrollView>
```

Problem is that it won't show any picture and I don't know what am I doing wrong here. I tried to pass it to new Activity, but it's too big. Also I tried to change `jpg` to `png` according to first tutorial mentioned, no difference. Also I tried this advice for Dialog https://stackoverflow.com/a/6045066/2966401 ..but again, it showed blank.

Comment: What is `imgView` and is it attached to some view hierarchy? Is `bp` non-null i.e. the decode works?

Comment: Added declaration, bp is not null. Any idea?

Comment: Ok, how is the layout where the attachment ImageView is?

Comment: Added layout, tried out an advice with `blobAsBytes` shown below, didn't worked.

Comment: News: Tried to scale down the bitmap and it showed up, but small. Do you think it's possible to open it in big size? Problem is, that I can't send to another Activity such big data to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Just u can use like this

```
Blob ImgByte = _CreditDetails.getBlob("ImageName");

            Drawable image = null;
            int blobLength = (int) ImgByte.length();  
            byte[] blobAsBytes = ImgByte.getBytes(1, blobLength);
            //release the blob and free up memory. (since JDBC 4.0)
            ImgByte.free();
            image =  new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blobAsBytes, 0, blobAsBytes.length));
Imageview.setBackgroundDrawable(image);
```

Try this one dude..this one helpful for you.

Comment: Actually Sqlite already returns byte array, I don't think I have to use ResultSet and JDBC as you are suggesting, if I understanded your first line well, because there are no declarations..

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't resolve the ResultSet with SQLite or what is that you have in `_CreditDetails` because of some null exception, but I combined your advice with my byte array which I get from my database and it didn't work, again blank ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

OK Try  this one bro.

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.attachment); 
byte b[] = db.getAttachment(task.id);
Drawable image = null;
image =  new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0,b.length));
Imageview.setBackgroundDrawable(image);
```